# Https callable cloud function not returning value

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions, braintree

I have a Flutter app and I'm trying to get a client nonce from braintree. Per the [braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/node), I have this in my cloud function:

```
exports.getClientNonce = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Error getting client nonce');
        } else {
            console.log(`token: ${response.clientToken}`);
            return response.clientToken;
        }
    });
});
```

Then, in my Flutter app I call the function (again, I'm following what the [plugin says](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions)):

```
try {
    HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
        functionName: 'getClientNonce',
    );

    dynamic result = await callable.call({});
    final value = result.data;  

    debugPrint('token: $value');

    var data = await BraintreePayment().showDropIn(
        nonce: value,
        amount: '2.0',
        enableGooglePay: false,
        inSandbox: true);
        print("Response of the payment $data");
    } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
        debugPrint('An error occurred');
    } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('An error occurred');
    }
}
```

I tried changing the cloud function so that it only returns a random number (as soon as the function is executed), and my Flutter app is correctly receiving the value (so the cloud function is communicating fine). And in my Firebase console, I am able to view the client nonce specified by `console.log`. But the function is for whatever reason unable to return the actual client nonce. (It should be should be some string hash that is >2000 characters long)

Comment: First thing is to ensure that your project is on a paid plan, as on a free plan you can only call Google-hosted services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callable function needs to return a promise from the top-level of the function callback that resolves with the value to return. Right now, you're returning nothing from the top-level.  The return you have now is just returning a value from the inner callback function that you pass to braintree API.  This isn't going to propagate to the top level.

What you need to do is either use a version of braintree API that returns an API (if one exists), or [promisify](https://javascript.info/promisify) the existing call that uses a callback.

See also "3. Node style callback" here: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

I have not tested this, but the general format if you apply that pattern will look more like this:

```
exports.getClientNonce = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Error getting client nonce'));
            } else {
                console.log(`token: ${response.clientToken}`);
                resolve(response.clientToken);
            }
        });
    });
});
```